# Handling incorrect non binary labellling when labelling objects in a greyscale image by tile

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, imagej

I am working on a project where I have a model which  does instance segmentation to segment nuclei in a image. Next step would be to label these segmented nuclei.  I am scaling the labeling by processing images as tiles.

The issue I am facing now is to come up with a way to handle incorrect labeling. Basically , when there  is  a object which gets split due to tiling  they are labelled  differently .

```
tile_size = 2048
  for x in range(0, vec_arr.shape[2], tile_size):
                        x_max = min([vec_arr.shape[2], x + tile_size])
                        for y in range(0, vec_arr.shape[1], tile_size):
                            y_max = min([vec_arr.shape[1], y + tile_size])
```

The above code explains how I am tiling a image. I am using this repo(https://github.com/MouseLand/cellpose/blob/master/cellpose/dynamics.py#L574) as the basis for labeling  images since I am using their network. I am looking for ideas on how I can identify objects which are connected across tiles  and fill them with same values.

Currently I maintain a counter of number of objects labelled in a tile and start labeling from that value.

I am interested in knowing on how I can identify same objects across tiles.

Answer (score 1):

This is not easy.

First of all you need an overlap in your tiling. Each tile should overlap the surrounding ones by some amount, which you then cut off when recomposing the larger image. The overlap amount should be at least the size of a nucleus, but preferably larger. The extra space is meant to guarantee that a nucleus that straddles the tile edge is detected identically in the two tiles where you can see it.

Next, when cutting off the overlap region and decomposing the larger image, a nucleus that straddles the tile edge (is partially in the overlap region) must be either preserved entirely or removed completely depending on which tile it “belongs to”. There are different ways to define this. For example, you can compute the centroid of the nucleus, and determine in which tile that is, and remove the nucleus from the other tile.

Thus, each nucleus is detected in exactly one tile. However, if the overlap region is not large enough, then a detection for a nucleus might not have the same shape in the two overlapping tiles, leading to two different centroids for the same nucleus. In this case, the nucleus could be perceived as not part of either tile, or part of both tiles. It is important to understand the detection algorithm, so that you can find the right overlap size that will guarantee identical detection for the two tiles.

Comment: Thanks  for your input. I have implemented tile overlapping . Using the centroids  I will have the info of which tile the object belongs to. What are ways in which I can  detect  an object  in the next tile  which  has centroid in previous tile or vice versa?  
This is  so that  same value is filled across tiles.

Comment: @war_wick: maybe the simplest is to copy over the objects from your tile into the output image, but only those objects that “belong to” the tile. Another approach is to delete the objects in the overlap area that do not belong to the tile (including the parts that are within the tile). This is a bit of bookkeeping, but not complicated. The hardest part is to get the detection to be consistent across tiles.